# How can an object find that is rvalue reference(unnamed value) in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I have a class named Matrix. I want overload operator ! that return transpose of matrix.
When the main matrix is a unnamed object I prefer to use it's allocated memory to construct transpose matrix, otherwise use new matrix. How can I do this.(We assume that the number of rows and columns of the matrix is ​​equal)

```
class Matrix {
// ...
/* transpose of a unnamed matrix */
Matrix&& operator !() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols_; ++j)
            std::swap(data[i][j],data[j][i]);
    return std::move(*this);
}

/* transpose of a matrix that is not rvalue refrence */
Matrix operator !()const
{
        Matrix ret(cols_, rows_);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols_; ++j)
                ret.data[j][i] = data[i][j];
        return temp;
}
};
```

The compiler does not allow me to have both overload together.

Comment: I think those are supposed to be member functions (OP uses `this`). Have a look at "reference-qualifiers" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions. Those are missing from your definition.

Comment: You are changing the meaning of `operator!` which is not recommended. Other than that, you can just qualify your member functions as rvalue `&&` or lvalue-only `&` just like cv qulifications. In C++20 you can also use the explicitly deduced `this` too.

Comment: Always post error along with your question. Also, **this is not what `operator!` is supposed to do**.

Comment: Please add a comment if you have a new thing. Operator! can have any meaning for any class.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use the member function.The compiler does not allow the use of two function with same name and arguments with two type return. Unless I pass main matrix as argument that I don't like to do that.

Comment: Unrelated: You can often avoid swapping values or new allocations in memory by creating a "transpose view" into your data: https://godbolt.org/z/Tscn1zEoT, but if that is feasible to you depends on your use case and application

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with ref-qualifiers:

```cpp
// (Also I would recommend you return by value here to prevent dangling references. You can still move from *this.)
Matrix&& operator !() && {  // Called on rvalues
    // ...
}
Matrix operator !() const& {  // Called on lvalues (and const rvalues)
    // ...
}
```

You could also write it as a free function:

```cpp
// (Or have these outside the class)
friend Matrix&& operator!(Matrix&& mat) {
    // ...
}
friend Matrix operator!(const Matrix& mat) {
    // ...
}

// You can also take by value instead so the move or copy is at the call site
friend Matrix operator!(Matrix mat) {
    // ... (in place transpose mat)
}
```

---

And as people have pointed out in the comments, `!x` *usually* means `!static_cast<bool>(x)`, and under the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), you should probably not make it do something different.

Consider `operator~`, or a friend function `T` (`T(mat)` looks pretty self explanatory)

Comment: Yes you are right. Operator ~ is better chose‍♂️. But this operator can used also for inverse of matrix and the user should refer to document of library to know what do it. Also operator ! that return bool has not any specific meaning for Matrix class and user must read document also. So m.t() is best choice.

Comment: Or T(m)........